# How to display shipping estimate and auto add this to grand total on cart page?

Tags: php, cart, shipping, grand-total

I am currently working on a magento website and trying to get the estimated shipping charge auto added to the grand total on the cart page. By doing this on the cart page I am trying to remove one of the steps later on in the check out process.

So to clarify and explain what i am trying to achieve It wold be best to explain it from a shoppers point of view.

1-Customer finds products
2-adds to cart
3-redirects to cart page
4-on this page it displays his cart along with the estimated shipping and tax block
5-Here customer enters his postcode and clicks button to get the shipping charges
6-The shipping charge is then shown which he has to select and then click update total.
7- The page will then load and update the grand total.

Now what I am trying to achieve is on step 5 when the customer enters his postcode and clicks get shipping. I would like the page to load and auto select the first or in my case the only shipping charge and also update the grand total. So there is no need for any action from the users part. He just has to click checkout to move to check out page.

I have looked in to the cart.phtml and shipping.phtml files. However i am not able to figure out how to achieve the above.

Advice and guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks